# Drillthrough a column of a matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following page :

[image: amirabedhiafi_0-1634386147135.png]

I want to click on the name of the agent to move to report with more details for an agent, this is a simplified example:

[image: amirabedhiafi_1-1634386905425.png]

Can I include filters in the detailed target page ?If yes, can I add a clear filters butto?

In this matrix, can I format only the Agent name ? Make the color blue and the font underlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I include filters in the detailed target page ?

Yes.  It's the nature of Drill-Through to carry the active filters from the source page to the target page.  If you want to include filters that aren't specifically included as drill-through filters, then there is a specific setting "Keep all filters" that governs this.  Your detail page can also have it's own set of slicers and filters that will be applied regardless of the context that comes through via drill-through actions.

> If yes, can I add a clear filters button?

There's one native in the service.   You can also affect the filters using the filter pane.  And you can add a bookmark that will restore the page to some pre-set state (without filters) and assign that bookmark to a button.  That's a tiny bit different than removing filters, but for most folks it's close enough

> In this matrix, can I format only the Agent name ?

Yes, but only in this simple case.  Look for the 'Row Headers' and control formatting there.  In Matrix visuals where there are hierarchal fields, they will all be colored by this setting so it will not just be agent names.   Another approach would be to apply editing to subtotals and mark 'include label' and then turn the subtotals off.   You would get color on the subtotal row, but it would show on every column.

> Make the color blue and the font underlined

You can set the font color on 'Row Headers' to blue.  Underscore is not an option.